# Vue.set insert an item at a specific index

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

this is my `items` object:

```
items: {
    houses:{
      name: 'Houses',
      url: '/houses',
      icon: 'icon-home',
    },
    users:{
      name: 'Users',
      url: '/users',
      icon: 'icon-people',
    },
}
```

I use vue.set to add item in my `items` object:

```
Vue.set(nav.items, 'agency_home', 
   {name: 'Agency',
   url: '/pages/404',
   icon: 'icon-home'}
)
```

This code works, it adds it after the `users` key. However, I want to add it after the the `houses` key.

Comment: if you want it specifically ordered, you're better off using an array

Comment: how would I do it if it is an array?

Comment: you would use splice

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `set`, you would use the `splice` array method, which will invoke the update.